# Literal values for tuple parameters in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I'm aware that I can assign a generic to a tuple type based on the input value of a function, for example

```
declare function example<A extends [any,...any[]]>(a: A) : A
example([1,2,3,[4]]) // : [ number, number, number, number[] ]
```

However I'd like the literal values, like so

```
example([1,2,3,[4]]) // : [ 1, 2, 3, [4] ]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hmm.. I think i figured out! Anyone interested?

Comment: Nice trick with the `[any, ...any[]]` to infer a tuple type.  I'm assuming you ended up doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52472549)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. When picking a type to instantiate a type variable, Typescript has to choose a single type for `A`. What you want is to instantiate `A` with four different types at once.