# How to force read-only arrays to have a tuple type with string literals in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a configuration object as follows:

```
const config = { envs: ['dev', 'test', 'prod'], targets: ['> 2%'] };
```

Currently, the typescript compiler infers the type of this object to be:

```
type IConfig = { envs: string[], targets: string[] };
```

Which makes sense as I might mutate this array at some point after declaration.

I'm not going to change it though, so I'd like it to be:

```
type IConfig = { envs: ['dev', 'test', 'prod'], targets: ['> 2%'] };
```

Is there any way to tell the compiler to infer the type of `config.envs` as a tuple type with string literals (without typing it out)?

Edit: The best answer is 90% of the way there, but I'm hoping for a method that can be applied to the object as a whole rather than each of the properties. I've added another property to the examples to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining [the standard trick to infer literal types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51985001) with [a trick I just learned to infer a tuple type rather than an array type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52471849):

```
function asTupleOfLiterals<T extends string, U extends [T, ...T[]]>(tuple: U): U {
    return tuple;
}
const config = { envs: asTupleOfLiterals(['dev', 'test', 'prod']) };
```

### Round 2: applying to an object with multiple tuple-valued properties

Miraculously, if we just wrap `[T, ...T[]]` in an object with an index signature, the contextual typing seems to work:

```
function asObjectOfTuplesOfLiterals<T extends string,
    U extends {[n: string]: [T, ...T[]]}>(obj: U): U { return obj; }

const config = asObjectOfTuplesOfLiterals(
    { envs: ['dev', 'test', 'prod'], targets: ['> 2%'] });
```

FTR, there's [an open suggestion to make it easier to infer literal types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10195) and [one to make it easier to infer tuple types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16656).

Comment: Can be simplified a [bit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20asTupleOfLiterals%3CT%20extends%20string%5B%5D%3E(...args%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20args%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20config%20%3D%20%7B%20envs%3A%20asTupleOfLiterals('dev'%2C%20'test'%2C%20'prod')%20%7D%3B)

Comment: These are super useful - thanks to both of you. I don't think I explained this well enough, but I'm hoping for a method that can be applied to the object as a whole rather than to each of the properties. I've added another property to my examples to make this clearer. The properties will always be arrays of strings. Apologies!